# How to make a pivot table with the index and values in Python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Give a example:

data:

```
    Group1  Group2 date value1  value2
0   A   01/20/20    0   1
1   A   01/25/20    0   3
2   A   02/28/20    0   2
3   B   01/25/20    0   1
4   B   01/27/20    2   2
5   C   01/29/20    0   5
6   C   01/30/20    2   6
```

I want get a pivot table to count the frequences of different values in Group2 and make Group2 column the index of the Final table. It's very easy when the index and value of the pivot table are not the same using pandas in python. While when they are same Python will raise a error, I can't solve this problem.

The output I want get is a table like the following table to get the frequency of different values in column 'Group 1' of the data:

| Group 1 | Frequency |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 2 |

Comment: Why don't you provide the code you used, the expected output, and your error? Do you want a simple `groupby.sum`?

Comment: As what I say in this question, I want get a table like the following table:
Group1  Values
A                3
B                2
C               1

Comment: Please provide the code and exact/explicit output directly in the question

Comment: Thanks for your help, let me try the function `groupby.sum`

Comment: OK, so you want a `df.groupby('Group2', as_index=False).agg(Frequency=('Group2', 'count'))`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your desired output looks like, but I sounds like you are looking for something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""
Group1,Group2,date,value1,value2
0,A,01/20/20,0,1
1,A,01/25/20,0,3
2,A,02/28/20,0,2
3,B,01/25/20,0,1
4,B,01/27/20,2,2
5,C,01/29/20,0,5
6,C,01/30/20,2,6
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep = ",")

pd.crosstab(index=df['Group2'], columns=[df['value1'], df['value2']], 
                normalize='index')
```

Output

```
value1         0                             2     
value2         1         2         3    5    2    6
Group2                                             
A       0.333333  0.333333  0.333333  0.0  0.0  0.0
B       0.500000  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.5  0.0
C       0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.5  0.0  0.5
```

Or are you just inerested in one value column?

```py
pd.crosstab(index=df['Group2'], columns=df['value2'], 
                normalize='index')
```

Output

```
value2         1         2         3    5    6
Group2                                        
A       0.333333  0.333333  0.333333  0.0  0.0
B       0.500000  0.500000  0.000000  0.0  0.0
C       0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.5  0.5
```

Comment: I want to make a pivot table to get the frequency of   different values in column 'Group 1' of the data. The output is just like this：
|Group 1   | Frequency  |
|---|---|
| A  | 3  |
| B  | 2  |
| C  | 2  |
`pd.pivot_table`seems to raise an error when the `index` parameter and the `values` parameter are the same. I don't know how to solve this problem in the beginning. I succeeded in handling with it using `pd.groupby().count()`.